# MS SQL Server slow network performance (ASYNC_NETWORK_IO) with fast network 10Gbit

Tags: sql-server, performance, networking, sql-server-2012

I got a MS SQL DB server (huge physical machine) and a application server (C# tool on VM). The application needs to read large data sets from the DB server (tables with millions of rows and multiple GB in size).

When run a select statement from the app server I get a ASYNC_NETWORK_IO wait on the server and not more than 50-100Mbit network utilization although I have a 10Gbit line between them. When I transfer a large file over the normal Windows file share it get to approx 10Gbit (so the network as such is fast).

I have tried to change the driver: OLEDB vs ODBC (v13).And I have tried to change the network package size from very small 1kb to 32kb.
No luck to improve it so far.

Can you give me some hints what I could try next?

A change of the application or the way the data gets transferred (bulk instead of direct query) are not an option.

> SQL Server 2012 (11.0.6579) (physical, MS 2012R2, 380GB RAM, 10GBit)
>   App Server (VM, MS 2012 R2, 128GB ram, 10Gbit)

Comment: You could test how fast you can get the data to the same server using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017). That would rule out anything network related.

Comment: Perhaps the client is CPU bound consuming the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits are almost never due to a slow network! (They are misleadingly named)

It's usually a client app that cannot consume data fast enough. i.e. SQL server is sending data faster than your application can consume.

Culprits are often client apps that process data row-by-row. Is the data being sent to a UI?

You mention that your app server is on a VM. Does the VM have a memory reservation set at the host?

If you are running SSMS on the app server, you can test the speed by changing the SSMS option **“Discard results after execution in SSMS”**:

[image]

SSMS can be quite slow to redraw data. With this option set, SSMS will read all the data off the wire, but it won't show you the data.  This will enable you to run queries at the speed that SQL server can run at and not be crippled by the client application speed.

Joe Sack's [advice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joesack/2009/01/08/troubleshooting-async_network_io-networkio/) is quite old but still relevant:

> I thought I would share prescriptive guidance on what to do if you see
>   `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` or `NETWORKIO` wait types:
>
> - Identify large result sets and verify with the application team (or developers) how this is being consumed.   Red flags include the
>     application querying large results sets but not processing more than a
>     few rows at a time
> - Ensure that the client application processes all rows it is requesting.   If not all rows will be needed or used - consider only
>     querying the rows that are needed (TOP X for example)
> - Look at your NIC configuration on the server and make sure there are no issues (physical card issue, autodetect not picking the fastest
>     speed)
> - Validate the network components between the application/clients and the SQL Server instance (router, for example)
>
> As a side note - if you are doing server-side data loads that are
>   still showing NETWORKIO, check to see if shared memory protocol is
>   enabled for the SQL Server instance (and then check to see if session
>   is connected using net_transport = ‘Shared memory” via
>   sys.dm_exec_connections).

Comment: Thanks! You got me on the right track. I knew that this option exists but I got distracted by the network utilization. Anyway I need to reach out to the vendor and find out why they are not processing the rows fast enough in the application.

Comment: happy to assist!